# Catalina can not access multiple partitioned HD over USB3 with FUSE

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, usb

An external HDD has multiple partitions, NTFS, FAT32, ext3, ext4.

When mounting external HDD over USB3, only the NTFS partition is visible in the apps Finder and Disk Utility.

FUSE **was** installed on mac.

What are required steps to mount all partitions, at least for reading?

I attempted to use *diskutil* to list and mount the partitions.

NTFS using command below was successful:

> diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk2s1

Other partitions failed to mount for one of the reasons shown below:

- Unable to find disk for
- or
- Volume on disk2s5 failed to mount. Perhaps the operation is not supported (kDAReturnUnsupported)

Comment: Did you install modules for these other filesystems?  macOS supports NTFS on its own without any help from FUSE (for r/o use).

Comment: I downloaded and installed package from here https://osxfuse.github.io/. exFat on USB drive appears to be working. Any links to recent articles and downloads appreciated.